# Rails and compressed table data mysql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have connected my rails application to MySQL database, I have noticed that data in some tables are compressed.

Here is an example of data selected of first record in one of the tables.

```
irb(main):024:0> data
=> #<Events_Full_Sections event_id: 1, a_full: "x\x9C\xD3\xD55447HN5H\xD2u\xD4\xD5\xE5\x8A60\xD3wKM\xD27204\xB324\xB425\xB622Q\xD0
\xD55050\x88U\b+\x8A...", b_full: "x\x9C]\x90OO\e1\x10\xC5\xEF\xFE\x14s\x04j{\xBC\xF9\xB3\xD0E=\xA4\b\x91\nh+\xD8(g\xC7;\xD9\xB5\x
E2\xB5\x8D\xD7!\x11\x9F\x9E%\xA5=\xF44O...", c_full: "x\x9C\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01", e_full: "x\x9C\xC5;\xFBo\xDB8\xD2?o\xFE\nF\x
C5F\xF6\xAE\xF5r\x1EN\x93\xC8A/mq\xFD\xD0\xDE\x15M\x8B\xC5\xA1)\nJ\xA2m\xA5\x92\xA8\x95\xE4$\xBEl\xFE...", f_full: "x\x9Cu\xCBAK\x
C30\x14\xC0\xF1{>E\xD8\xFD%\xCD\x8A\xA8\x99\x9D\xA00\x06\x0E\xEC\xA1\x82\xD7.>\x9Aj\x9A\x17\x92\a\xDD\xBE\xBD-\x88\x17\xF1\xFA\xE7
\xF7\a0...", h_full: "x\x9Cu\x90Ak\xC2@\x10\x85\xEF\xFB+\x06O\nn\x92\xDD$FS\xF6\xD0j\xC0Bk\x8A\xF1\xD2S\x89\xBBS#5\xBBa\x934\xF5\x
DFw\xD5\x82\xA72\xF0\xDE...", i_full: "x\x9C\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01", k_full: "x\x9C\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01", z_full: "--1170ce0
b-Z--\n", compressed: true>
```

I have tried using a function to decompress, something like this

```
  def decompress(text)
    Zlib::Inflate.new(-Zlib::MAX_WBITS).inflate(Base64.decode64(text))
  end
```

And when I call this function, I'm getting the following:

```
irb(main):032:0> decompress(d)
NoMethodError: undefined method `unpack' for #<Events_Full_Sections:0x66d3dd0>
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activemodel-4.2.5.2/lib/
 `method_missing'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/base64.rb:58:in `decode64'
        from (irb):20:in `decompress'
```

Any idea what could be wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `decompress` function expects a string in Base64 encoding on input, but you're feeding it with a model instance, which is not a string.

Also fields themselves do not look like base64, more like a raw zlib-compressed.

Try `Zlib.inflate(d.a_full)` (and so on)